# Self-referencing Vue component not rendering in built nuxt project

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am implementing a custom dropdown component using Vue. The dropdown component itself can contain a hierarchy of selectable items. The linked screenshot describes its purpose pretty well, I guess. [Dropdown component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwGq2.png)

The two components I use for this are listed below.

**Dropdown.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="dropdown" v-click-outside="setInactive">
    <div class="dropdown__single">
      <div class="dropdown__select dropdown__select--hidden">
        <select @change="$emit('onValueChange', value)">
          <template>
            <option :value="value" selected> Select option</option>
            <option :value="value"> option A</option>
          </template>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown__custom-select " :class="{...}">
        <span class="dropdown__custom-current" @click="showList"
              :class="{...}">
            {{ values[0] || 'Select option' }} 
        </span>
        <ul class="dropdown__custom-list" v-if="params.itemparams">

          <DropdownItem @changeListener="onChildValueChange" :params="item" v-for="(item, index) in params.itemparams"
                        :key="index" :active="false" :index="index" :depth="1" @opened="onChildOpened"
                        @closed="onChildClosed"/>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';
import DropdownItem from './DropdownItem.vue';

@Component({
  components: {
    DropdownItem
  },
})
export default class Dropdown extends Vue {
...
}
</script>
```

This component is the basic dropdown component. The following component is the dropdown item referenced by the dropdown component:

**DropdownItem.vue**

```html
<template>
  <li :class="...">

    <span v-else :class="{ 'dropdown__custom-list-item-span': subChildsHasNoItems() }"
          @click="emitChange()">
      {{ params.headline }}
    </span>

    <ul v-if="subChildrenHaveItems()" class="dropdown__custom-sublist">
      <DropdownItem v-for="(item, index) in params.subChildren" :index="index" :key="`${depth},${index}`" :params="item"
                    :depth="depth + 1"
      />
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: {
    DropdownItem
  }
})
export default class DropdownItem extends Vue {
...
}
</script>
```

This component renders fine in case I run `nuxt`. This means, that if I click on a DropdownItem that has children itself all those referenced DropdownItems are rendered as desired in the DOM:

```html
<div class="dropdown__single"> <!-- Here the dropdown component is rendered -->
    <div class="dropdown__select dropdown__select--hidden">
      <select>
        <option selected="selected" value="option Q"> Select option</option>
        <option value="option Q"> option A</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown__custom-select dropdown__custom-select--active">
      <span class="dropdown__custom-current dropdown__custom-current--active">Select option </span>
      <ul class="dropdown__custom-list">
        <li class="dropdown__custom-list-item--parent"> <!-- the first dropdown item component is rendered --> 
          <span
              class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span dropdown__custom-list-item-span--with-children dropdown__custom-list-item-span--with-children--active">
            <span class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span-checkbox"></span>
            <span class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span-content">Option A</span>
          </span>
          <ul class="dropdown__custom-sublist">
            <li class="dropdown__custom-list-item--parent"> <!-- the second dropdown item component is rendered -->
              <span class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span dropdown__custom-list-item-span--with-children">
                <span class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span-checkbox"></span> 
                <span class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span-content">Option AA</span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But once I build the project using `nuxt build` and start it afterwards (`nuxt start`) the child components are not rendered anymore:

```html
<div class="dropdown__single">  <!-- Here the dropdown component starts -->
    <div class="dropdown__custom-select dropdown__custom-select--active dropdown__custom-select--transparenz">
      <span class="dropdown__custom-current dropdown__custom-current--active">Select option </span> 
      <ul class="dropdown__custom-list">
        <li class="dropdown__custom-list-item--parent"> <!-- here the first dropdown item component starts -->
          <span class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span dropdown__custom-list-item-span--with-children dropdown__custom-list-item-span--with-children--active">
            <span class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span-checkbox"></span> 
            <span class="dropdown__custom-list-item-span-content">AS-Interface (112)</span>
          </span> 
          <ul class="dropdown__custom-sublist">
            <dropdownitem index="0" params="[object Object]" depth="2"></dropdownitem> 
            <!-- ERROR: here the second dropdown item component should be rendered but it is not -->
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can anyone help me fixing this problem and tell me why the built nuxt project does not render the self-referencing component?

*Edit: I added the import statement to the `Dropdown.vue` class for clearification.*

Comment: Where does `DropdownItem` come from in, `@Component({
  components: {
    DropdownItem
  }
})` ? Is there an import?

Comment: Yes, in fact there is an import statement above the component declaration
`import DropdownItem, { IDropdownItemParams } from './DropdownItem.vue';`
At least in the `Dropdown.vue` file.
In the `DropdownItem.vue` no import is necessary since the class declaration is in the same file.

Comment: No, it's necessary, `export default class DropdownItem` is class expression. The problem may be in how self-imports are handled, this is very specific to the implementation in use. It will clearly be different for yarn build, this is likely the case. Try to avoid it. It's unknown which Vue version you use, this limits the way in which this can be done.

Comment: I am using `vue 2.6.14` and nuxt `2.15.8`.

Comment: See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components . One of options is  `components: { DropdownItem: () => import('...')`, can't say if it works ok with Nuxt

Comment: In fact, that works fine. I also (just briefly) tested out creating a separate component `DropdownItemContent` which then could solve the self-referencing. But this way works even better. Thank you very much!